# For F such that $F(0)=0$ and $||F(\pm z)||_\beta=||z||_\alpha$, prove that $F(-z)=-F(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have Euclidean balls: $\mathbb{B}_\alpha \subset \mathbb{C}^\alpha$, $\mathbb{B}_\beta \subset \mathbb{C}^\beta$ and a function $F:\mathbb{B}_{\alpha}\to \mathbb{B}_\beta$ with $F(0)=0$ and I know that $||F(\pm z)||_\beta = ||z||_\alpha$,
how can I prove that $F(-z)=-F(z)$.
Here $||\cdot ||_n$ is the Euclidian norm. Intuitively it seems obvious but I'd be glad to see how to justify it. Thanks for your time and help!